# Do closed questions affect your accept rate?

Tags: discussion, closing

I had a question that was closed, so it came to me if it affected your "accept rate" for these examples:

If I asked a question, got **no** answer, and it got closed
If I asked a question, got **an** answer, got closed but never accepted the answer

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 4):

Closed questions do not affect your accept rate

Comment: Just to add, but in addition to the OP's given scenarios, this holds true even if the closed question had an answer that was accepted. If you hover over your accept rate, it'll tell you the number of eligible questions and how many have accepted answers.